# How to get all list of customer group?

Tags: magento2, customer, adminform, source-model

I have created admin form. I am able to get customer group list using below code, but there is no "NOT LOGIN" group name so how can I get all group list?

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$groupOptions = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer\Attribute\Source\Group')->getAllOptions();

$fieldset->addField(
    'customer_group',
    'multiselect',
    [
        'name' => 'customer_group[]',
        'label' => __('Customer Group'),
        'title' => __('Customer Group'),
        'values' => $groupOptions,
        'disabled' => $isElementDisabled
    ]
);
```

I am getting this output:

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I was able to get solution using the below code:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$groupOptions = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Group\Collection')->toOptionArray();

$fieldset->addField(
    'customer_group',
    'multiselect',
    [
        'name' => 'customer_group[]',
        'label' => __('Customer Group'),
        'title' => __('Customer Group'),
        'values' => $groupOptions,
        'disabled' => $isElementDisabled
    ]
);
```

Comment: I would like to sat this great answer

Answer (score 9):

You can use the following class: `Magento\Customer\Model\Customer\Source\Group`.

It provides a `toOptionArray` method that you can use to get an array of customer groups

Comment: Class Magento\Customer\Model\Customer\Source\Group does not exist

Comment: @PrashantValanda you probably made a typo: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Customer/Model/Customer/Source/Group.php

Comment: I am using magento 2.0.0. check here is no source folder http://prntscr.com/blm5ej

Comment: I used this in a custom extension in the system config field as select option via <field id="public" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="50" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Public/Guest Group</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Customer\Model\Customer\Source\Group</source_model>
                </field>